# anyone please guide me how can i do web scarping multiple pages of booking.com -

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is the link url

```
url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_c

Hotel_name = doc.find_all("div",{'class' : "fcab3ed991 a23c043802"})
```

this gives me the result of all hotel names in page number, 1, but how can I get the hotel names of all the pages?

I've tried this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Initialize the page number
page_number = 0

while True:
    # Increment the page number
    page_number += 1
    
    # Make the GET request to the URL
    url = f"https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&nflt=ht_id%3D204&rows=15&offset={page_number*15}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # Extract the hotel information
    hotels = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "fcab3ed991 a23c043802"})
    if not hotels:
        break
    for hotel in hotels:
        price = hotel.find('div', {' data-testid="title'}).text
        print(f"{price}")
```

but it gives me an empty list as an output.

Comment: Using `requests` to fetch the page is probably already doomed to failure, because it can't process javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid selecting elements by classes that looks highly dynamic and use HTML structure instead. Check the number of total results and use it in `range()` to iterate the results.

##### Example

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&nflt=ht_id%3D204&rows=15',
                headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
                ).text)

num_results = int(re.search(r'\d+',soup.select_one('div:has(+[data-testid="pagination"])').text).group(0))

for i in range(0,int(num_results/25)):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(f'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&nflt=ht_id%3D204&rows=15&offset={int(i*25)}',
                headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
            ).text
    )
    data.extend([e.select_one('[data-testid="title"]').text for e in soup.select('[data-testid="property-card"]')])

data
```

Comment: Please do not spam the comments - Focus on question and describe exactly what your issue is. It is the link from your example, only added `offset={int(i*25)}` in the loop but no changes as into your second link from the comments.

Comment: sure I will sorry for that actually it is the 1st time I am using this platform that is why it happened.

Comment: hello why this code is not working when i am tring to get location and reviews with hotel name plz help