# How to create DataFrame with columns based on scraped data?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&nflt=ht_id%3D204&rows=15',
                headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
                ).text)

num_results = int(re.search(r'\d+',soup.select_one('div:has(+[data-testid="pagination"])').text).group(0))

for i in range(0,int(num_results/25)):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(f'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&nflt=ht_id%3D204&rows=15&offset={int(i*25)}',
                headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
            ).text
    )
    data.extend([e.select_one('[data-testid="title"]').text for e in soup.select('[data-testid="property-card"]')])
   data.extend([e.select_one('[class="d8eab2cf7f c90c0a70d3 db63693c62"]') for e in soup.select('[data-testid="property-card"]')])

data
```

[image]

I am getting name and reviews for all pages in a single line, i want to get this result in separate columns for names and reviews.

I want to get my result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I couldn't understand your question, what do yo want. If you could show a sample dataframe you want it would be great. But generally you can do it like that. For example in this data latitude longitude is in same column and you can separate them to two columns with split function. Don't forget to add headers.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import datetime


base_url = 'https://www.booking.com'
urlss = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?req_children=0&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&group_children=0&dest_type=city&rows=15&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&nflt=ht_id%3D204&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_adults=2'

data = []
def pars(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    foor = {}
    try:
        foor['description'] = soup.find('div', id = 'property_description_content').text
        foor['Title'] = soup.find('h2', class_  = 'd2fee87262 pp-header__title').text
        x = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'a815ec762e ab06168e66')
        div_map = soup.select_one('#hotel_sidebar_static_map')
        if div_map:
            foor['x_lnge'] = div_map['data-atlas-latlng']

        for f in range(0, len(x)):
           foor[f'feature{f}'] =(x[f].text)
        data.append(foor)
    except:
        None
def general():
    r = requests.get(urlss)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    x = soup.select('header > a')
    for f in x:
        urls = base_url + f['href']
        obj = {}
        obj['urls'] = urls
        print(urls)
        pars(urls)




f = []
def export_data(data):
    f = pd.DataFrame(data)
    f = f.drop_duplicates()
    presentday = datetime.now()
    pese = str(presentday)
    a = str(presentday)[0:10].replace('-', '_')
    f.to_excel(f'{a}booking.xlsx', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    general()
    export_data(data)
```

Comment: hello thank you so much for the help i just added a picture of the output that i want please once check it.

Comment: For the address you can use latitude and longitude. Use geolocator it will give you exact address. For distance from center also you can use lat and lng's. Define a center and create a def funcion distance_locator .

Comment: You can crawl rating and review without parsing. I just show you an example you have to modify it for your on work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adapt my answer from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75270151/14460824 and select all needed information from detail pages.

Instead of extending the `list` with lists append `dicts`.

##### Example

Be aware, this example breaks after first iteration for demo purposes, simply remove `break` from loop to get all results, also adapt handling of check if elements ar available.

```
import requests, re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&nflt=ht_id%3D204&rows=15',
                headers={'user-agent':'some agent bond'}
                ).text)

num_results = int(re.search(r'\d+',soup.select_one('div:has(+[data-testid="pagination"])').text).group(0))

for i in range(0,int(num_results/25)):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(f'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGyIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuS4sJ4GwAIB0gIkYWJlYmZiMWItNWJjMi00M2Y2LTk3MGUtMzI2ZGZmMmIyNzMz2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&dest_id=-2092174&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&req_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&nflt=ht_id%3D204&rows=15&offset={int(i*25)}',
                headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
            ).text
    )
    for e in soup.select('[data-testid="property-card"]'):
        data.append({
            'title': e.select_one('[data-testid="title"]').text,
            'score': e.select_one('[data-testid="review-score"]').contents[0].text if e.select_one('[data-testid="review-score"]') else None,
            'ratings': e.select_one('[data-testid="review-score"]').text.split()[-2],
            'address':e.select_one('[data-testid="address"]').text,
            'distance':e.select_one('[data-testid="distance"]').text
        })
    break
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | title | score | ratings | address | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Hotel Ariana Residency | 7 | 179 | Western Suburbs, Mumbai | 17.7 km from centre |
| 1 | MAXX VALUE - HOTEL KOHINOOR CONTINENTAL | 7.4 | 12 | Western Suburbs, Mumbai | 16.7 km from centre |
| 2 | West End Hotel Opp Bombay Hospital | 7.1 | 168 | South Mumbai, Mumbai | 3.3 km from centre |
| 3 | The Leela Mumbai | 8.6 | 2,536 | Western Suburbs, Mumbai | 16.6 km from centre |
| 4 | Marriott Executive Apartment - Lakeside Chalet, Mumbai | 7.8 | 265 | Powai, Mumbai | 20.1 km from centre |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | Taj Santacruz | 8.8 | 2,980 | Mumbai | 14.2 km from centre |
| 21 | Hotel Suncity Residency | 6.9 | 56 | Western Suburbs, Mumbai | 17.3 km from centre |
| 22 | Niranta Transit Hotel Terminal 2 Arrivals/Landside | 7.6 | 2,380 | Andheri, Mumbai | 15.5 km from centre |
| 23 | JW Marriott Mumbai Juhu | 8.4 | 1,318 | Juhu, Mumbai | 14.8 km from centre |
| 24 | Hotel Bawa Continental | 7.9 | 754 | Juhu, Mumbai | 14.7 km from centre |