# Beautifulsoup is creating an empty csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Set the URL to scrape
url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?ss=Hurghada&sb=1'

# Send a request to the URL and get the page content
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content

# Parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup (content)
print(soup)
# Find the hotel elements
hotels = soup.find_all('div', {'data-testid="property-card"'})[:10]
print(hotels)

# Create a CSV file to save the hotel data
csv_file = open ( 'booking.csv' , 'w' , newline='' , encoding='utf-8' )
writer = csv.writer ( csv_file )

# Write the header row to the CSV file
writer.writerow ( [ 'Hotel Name' , 'Score' , 'Review Count' , 'Price' ] )

# Loop through the first 10 hotels and extract the data
for hotel in hotels [ :10 ]:
    # Extract the hotel name
    name = hotel.find ( 'div' , class_='sr-hotel__name' ).text.strip ( )

    # Extract the hotel score
    score = hotel.find ( 'div' , class_='bui-review-score__badge' ).text.strip ( )

    # Extract the review count
    review_count = hotel.find ( 'div' , class_='bui-review-score__text' ).text.strip ( )

    # Extract the price
    price = hotel.find ( 'div' , class_='sr_rooms_table_block__prices' ).text.strip ( )

    # Write the hotel data to the CSV file
    writer.writerow ( [ name , score , review_count , price ] )

# Close the CSV file
csv_file.close ( )
```

I am trying to make a csv file that has the following for the top 10 results:

1- Hotel Name

2- Rating Score, example 8.7 or 8

3- Rating Value, example Excellent or Very Good

4- Number of Reviews

The csv is coming up empty, and i cant find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.*

---

There are three main issues that causes the behavior leading to an empty CSV:

- Add a `user-agent` to your request headers, to get expected source:

  ```
  requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'some agent'})
  ```
- Check your selection and provide attributes in propper syntax:

  ```
  hotels = soup.find_all('div', {'data-testid':"property-card"})
  ```
- Before apply a methode check that an element exists.

May check also [existing answers for scraping booking.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75427065/14460824) that deals with alternative selections.